# Keycloak for Angular not sending bearer authentication for Images

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, keycloak

I am running an Angular application with a **Spring Boot MVC** API in combination with **Keycloak**. I configured Angular following the instruction found under https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular and it generally works fine.

In my Angular components I use the `img` tag to include Images, which are served by my Spring Boot application

```
<img *ngIf="id" src="api/v1/profile/image/{{id}}">
```

The MVC endpoint looks like this :

```
@GetMapping(value = "profile/image/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getProfileImage(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt, @PathVariable String id)
            throws IOException {
            ...
            }
```

**The problem is that** I receive a 401 Response Code on the first load of the image.

Here are my key findings:

- The load of the image does (never) contain the "authorization: bearer
  ..."  request header (as opposed to requests, that are sent via the
  `HttpClient`)
- The first failing request will have a `set-cookie`
  response Header
- Consecutive Requests will contain the cookie as part
  of the Request Header and will work

Can anybody point out, what I can do?  Can keycloak be configured in a way, that the load of Images will contain the bearer authetication header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img *ngIf="id" src="api/v1/profile/image/{{id}}">
```

This kind of image is loaded by the browser and not by `HttpClient`. And `HttpClient` is already configured to inject `Authorization` header in your case, not the browser so that is a root cause of the issue.

You may load image content from the URL `api/v1/profile/image/{{id}}` with `HttpClient` and then do a inlining of that image content into HTML with base64 encoding:

```
<img src="data:<correct content type>;base64, <base 64 data of the image content>" />

e.g.:
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

It is good solution for small images (this approach is used for social icons usually).

Or you can save authorization into cookie in the same format as your service provider is expecting  before you create image). Then browser will send that authorization cookie in the each request. Of course there can be a problem with cross domain cookies.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your reply. As I have profile pictures (photos) I presume the second option would work better for me. Could you please elaborate, how to set this cookie?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, I can't I don't know how cookie should looks like in your case, what are your domains, .... You already know `request will have a "set-cookie" response Header`, so just mimic that set-cookie in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Angular is powerful enough to satisfy your server requirements. You can force the `img` tag to request the image via an `HttpClient`.

So start with Writing a **pipe** that accepts an image url and performs the HTTP request *while putting on the Authorization header*.

The pipe can look like this:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'authImage'
})
export class AuthImagePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private auth: AuthService, // your service that provides the authorization token
  ) {}

  async transform(src: string): Promise<string> {
    const token = this.auth.getToken();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`});
    const imageBlob = await this.http.get(src, {headers, responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise();
  }

}
```

You also need to Transform the `blob` response to a `base64` string so it can be passed to the `src` attribute. Then put the `base64` string into a `Promise`, so that it can be passed to the `async` **pipe** in its turn. Here we provide them plus error handling (server errors like 40X, 50X) using *fallback image* altogether:

```
async transform(src: string): Promise<string> {
  const token = this.auth.getToken();
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`});
  try {
    const imageBlob = await this.http.get(src, {headers, responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob);
    });
  } catch {
    return 'assets/fallback.png';
  }
}
```

In this way, you can use sth like this:

```
<img [src]="'api/v1/profile/image/' | authImage | async"/>
```

You can also write an additional component for the new version of `img` tag like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'image',
  template: '<img [src]="src | authImage | async" [alt]="alt"/>',
})
export class ImageComponent {

  @Input() src: string;
  @Input() alt = '';
}
```

And then use it like this :

```
<image src="api/v1/profile/image/"></image>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [src] attribute in HTML is used to specify the source URL for an image, video, audio file, or any other external resource that is included in the web page, it's rather part of the HTML standard than angular.

A way to tweak it would be to use data binding.
Ex:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {
  imageUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.http.get('https://example.com/image.png', { responseType: 'blob' })
      .subscribe(blob => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        this.imageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
      });
  }
}

// In your template
<img [src]="imageUrl" />
```